# Postgres - Selecting a row after RETURNING multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query is

```
DELETE FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id = '1BZbAR'
returning parent_id, comment_id, thread_id
```

And it returns 3 rows

```
null | 1 | 1BZbAR
1    | 2 | 1BZbAR
2    | 3 | 1BZbAR
```

How do I select the row where parent_id is null?

I have tried:

```
DELETE FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id = '1BZbAR'
returning MIN(parent_id), comment_id, thread_id
```

```
DELETE FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id = '1BZbAR'
returning HAVING parent_id is null, comment_id, thread_id
```

```
DELETE FROM event_comments WHERE thread_id = '1BZbAR'
returning parent_id, comment_id, thread_id as t
SELECT * FROM t WHERE parent_id is null
```

However all of them give them syntax errors. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to subquery your current delete statement, or put it into a CTE and query that:

```
WITH cte AS (
    DELETE
    FROM event_comments
    WHERE thread_id = '1BZbAR'
    RETURNING parent_id, comment_id, thread_id
)

SELECT parent_id, comment_id, thread_id
FROM cte
WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```